# Not resolving domain with CoovaChilli: dropping malformed DNS

Tags: dns, raspbian, captiveportal, coovachilli

I have CoovaChilli 1.3.1.4 on Raspbian, with the DNS, DHCP and web server running altogether.

I need to resolve a domain named `app.mydomain.com`. When I start the system with CoovaChilli disabled I can access `app.mydomain.com`. But when CoovaChilli is enabled, the domain stops from being resolved. Others domains, however, are resolved normally.

So if I ping `app.mydomain.com` with CoovaChilli enabled I get:

```
ping: unknown host app.mydomain.com
```

Looking into `/var/log/daemon.log` I see the following message:

```
coova-chilli[803]: dropping dns for anti-dnstunnel (type 6: length 45)
coova-chilli[803]: dropping malformed DNS
```

Enabled settings on `/usr/local/etc/chilli/config` are:

```
HS_WANIF=eth0              # WAN Interface toward the Internet
HS_LANIF=wlan0             # Subscriber Interface for client devices
HS_NETWORK=192.168.42.0    # HotSpot Network (must include HS_UAMLISTEN)
HS_NETMASK=255.255.255.0   # HotSpot Network Netmask
HS_UAMLISTEN=192.168.42.1  # HotSpot IP Address (on subscriber network)
HS_UAMPORT=3990            # HotSpot UAM Port (on subscriber network)
HS_UAMUIPORT=4990          # HotSpot UAM "UI" Port (on subscriber network, for embedded portal)
HS_DNS1=127.0.0.1
HS_DNS2=8.8.8.8
HS_NASID=nas01
HS_RADIUS=localhost
HS_RADIUS2=localhost
HS_RADSECRET=testing123    # Set to be your RADIUS shared secret
HS_UAMSECRET=change-me     # Set to be your UAM secret
HS_UAMALIASNAME=chilli
HS_UAMDOMAINS=".mydomain.com"
HS_UAMSERVER=$HS_UAMLISTEN
HS_UAMFORMAT=https://app.mydomain.com/
HS_UAMHOMEPAGE=https://app.mydomain.com/
HS_REDIRDNSREQ=on
HS_DNSPARANOIA=on
HS_TCP_PORTS="80 443"
HS_MODE=hotspot
HS_TYPE=coovachilli
HS_LOC_NAME="My HotSpot"
```

Actually I'm using bind9 as DNS service.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Note: I didn't install Radius yet. I want to get this problem fixed before I decide if I'm going to use Radius for authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was only a misconfiguration. `HS_DNS1` should be `192.168.42.1` and not `127.0.0.1`.

Also, I forgot to include `app.mydomain.com` to the hosts file.

Now it's working.